# How to select different cell from the same row in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have this jQuery selector:

```
'table tbody tr td:first-of-type'
```

How can I construct a cell selector for the same row from $(this)? I need to check

```
 $(document).on('click','table tbody tr td:first-of-type',function()
 {
   if ( $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').text() != "" ) // for the same row !!
   //do something
   else
   //do something else
 }
```

Extra question: should I avoid using CSS3 selectors like nth-child() and use jquery selectors like eq() ?

Comment: Could you post some HTML and an example of what you want to achieve? Your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: you forgot some `'` in your selector, was it a typo? Should be `if( $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').text() != "" )`

Comment: @Sergio yes, just typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find the closest `tr`

```
$(this).closest("tr")
```

And to select a `td`, use `.find()` chained to that:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td") //and whatever criteria you need
```

Comment: and then how do you select the td that you need ?

Comment: is this the only way? doesn't look very efficient (in general case)

Comment: If you need to access more than one of the cells it would be advised to assign the result from "closest" to a variable. Then you could use the find on that variable to prevent having to rescan and find the TR again.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
   <html>
        <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
        if ($('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').text() != "" ){ // for the same row
       //do something
        // alert($('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').text());
        }else{
       //do something else
       //alert("test");
        }

           });
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>itemOne</td>
                <td>itemOneInfo</td>
                <td>Info</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```